# Is there a verb to describe an action which involves an insult to someone whom you just helped out?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

If someone helped me (financially or any kind of assistance) and when it comes to any disagreement, he starts to remind me of his help and brag about it.

Which verb that describes this situation where the subject is "someone" and the object is "me "?

Here is an imaginary conversation:

> Him: Don't forget that I once helped you.
>   Me: You keep repeating this day after day. Stop _____ me.

What should I add in the space?

Comment: Your question's title talks about **insult** but in the details you mention **bragging**. Which is it?

Comment: I mean bragging about his help in the negative sense .

Comment: I would have to think about a single word, but there is a common expression, "throwing it in your face" or "throwing it back in your face" which describes that action.

Comment: You got me wrong sir . May be because i didn't give a clear example.
Here is an imaginary conversation
him: don't forget that i once helped you .
me: you keep repeating this day after day .Stop ....... me.
What should i add in the space ?

Comment: You can use *brag* here. It makes perfect sense. He has something to brag about,which is him helping you out. Look up synonyms for *brag*. If you're not satisfied, come back here.

Comment: @israawael I think fixer1234 provided the perfect answer. "Stop throwing it in my face".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would you call a person who helps you only to later boast about it or repeatedly, emphatically mention it during a fight?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286659/what-would-you-call-a-person-who-helps-you-only-to-later-boast-about-it-or-repea)

Comment: The person is *holding it over you*, where *it* is the fact that s?he once helped you.

Comment: The suggestions from Drew and fixer are very good.

Answer (score 1):

Guilt-trip ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guilt-trip))

> to cause feelings of guilt in guilt-tripped them into helping

Example:

> Him: Don't forget that I once helped you.
>   Me: You keep repeating this day after day. Stop **guilt-tripping** me.

Answer (score 0):

To *snub* is a verb that comes to mind.  This is a bit more subtle than "Throw sth. back in someone's face" (or "Throw sth. back at someone"), meaning to 'ignore someone's efforts' rather than to verbally reject them (or *literally* throw a gift back at someone ;-) ).  It can also have a more general meaning of 'to ignore (someone) out of disdain or assumed superiority'.

Answer (score -1):

To *give a cold shoulder* could be the word you are looking for in this scenario. It seems slightly informal but does work.

Comment: A reference would be helpful; also the phrase doesn't fit in the OP's template. Are you sure it's responsive to the question?